# How to check Firebase deep link when the app is not install?

Tags: ios, objective-c, firebase, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

In my app, I have deep link from Firebase.

In this methods, I get the link when user have the app install.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
continueUserActivity:(NSUserActivity *)userActivity
 restorationHandler:(void (^)(NSArray *))restorationHandler
```

but when the user doesn't install my app, it takes him to the App Store and after the install, the app should open and call this method.

How can I check this without upload version to app store?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firebase doesn't know (or care) *how* the application is installed onto your device. Installing directly from Xcode and using a beta distribution system (TestFlight, Hockey, Fabric, etc.) are treated exactly the same way as going through the App Store.

Here is a flow you can use to test this:

1. Install a build of your app that includes the Dynamic Links SDK
2. Generate a link and post it somewhere like iOS Notes
3. Uninstall your app
4. Open the link and let it redirect all the way through to the App Store page
5. Close the App Store
6. Install a build of your app locally (using either Xcode or TestFlight/Fabric/etc.)
7. Open your app
8. The link data will be returned to you, exactly the same way it would be when your app is installed from the App Store by a user.

Comment: I try this from testFlight and from xcode, and the deep links methods in appdelaget not called.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with your code then — I can guarantee testing it this way from Xcode works just fine. Could you update your question with a more complete snippet from your AppDelegate?

Comment: Now its works grate (Xcode or testFlight) , I add [FIROptions defaultOptions].deepLinkURLScheme = @"com.my.pName";

Comment: @RoeiNadam where did you added [FIROptions defaultOptions].deepLinkURLScheme = @"com.my.pName" this code?
Can you please help me with it.

Comment: @raj Thandel in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions AppDelegate.m   [FIROptions defaultOptions].deepLinkURLScheme = @"com.blabla.blabla";
    
    [FIRApp configure];

Comment: @RoeiNadam Thanks. After watching videos on youtube finally my problem is solved. For any beginners struggling with firebase dynamic linking i must recommend to watch video on youtube. https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCP4bf6IHJJQehibu6ai__cg

Comment: This also works for Android (installing a local build after opening Google Play)